# fix $b \gt 1$. Prove the following statements : (Rudin page 22, question no 6)

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Fix $ b \gt 1$.

(a) If $m$, $n$, $p$, and $q$ are integers, $n \gt 0$, $q \gt 0$ and $r=\dfrac{m}{n}=\dfrac{p}{q}$, prove that $\{b^{m}\}^{\dfrac{1}{n}}=\{b^{p}\}^{\dfrac{1}{q}}$. Hence it makes sense to define $b^{r}=\left(b^{m}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{n}}$.

(b) Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^{r}b^{s}$ if $r$ and $s$ are rational.

(c) If $x$ is real, define $B(x)$ to be the set of all numbers $b^{t}$, where $t$ is rational and $t \le x$. Prove that $b^{r}=\sup B(r)$, where $r$ is rational. Hence it makes sense to define $b^{x}=\sup B(x)$ for every real $x$.

(d)Prove that $b^{x+y}=b^{x}b^{y}$ for all reals $x$ and $y$.

I am stuck in (b) and (d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a hint for part (b)** 
Let $r=m/n$ and $s=p/q$ where $m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n,q >0$. Then 
\begin{align*}
b^{r+s}&=\left(b^{mq+np}\right)^{1/nq}\\
& = \left(b^{mq} \cdot b^{np}\right)^{1/nq} & \text{using laws of exponents for integer powers}\\
& = \left(b^{mq}\right)^{1/nq} \left(b^{np}\right)^{1/nq}& \text{using corollary for Theorem 1.21}\\
\end{align*}

**Here is a hint for part (d)**

By the definition given $b^{x+y}=\sup B(x+y)$. Observe that any $t \in B(x+y)$ can be expressed as $t=r+s$, where $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $r<x$ and $s<y$. See if you can proceed from here/